# Toast.makeText Android show message on the top screen

Tags: popup, message

Can I show a popup message on top of screen ? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change where the message will be shown on the screen. See [Toast.setGravity(int gravity, int xOffset, int yOffset)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#setGravity%28int,%20int,%20int%29) and [Positioning your Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#Positioning)

Comment: Oh, I got a error when I use : Toast toast = new Toast(this)(or getApplicationContext()) , you know what's the reason?

Comment: What's the error? I can't know the reason if you don't provide at least the error message or the stack trace.

Comment: Hi, if we use new Toast(..) we can't use setText ,I replaced by Toast.makeText(..) ,thanks rebenlop88